# dynamic image source android

Tags: android

I am trying to make images dynamic in my android application. With the help of other posts i wrote this code but i am unable to set image resource. Here is my code.

```
// get image whose source i want to change..
ImageView IV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

// x for 1,2,3.. hangman1.png,hangman2.png and so on image are located
// under res/drawable-mdpi
int j = getResources().getIdentifier("hangman"+x, "imageView", getPackageName());

// here i get errork, The method setImageResource(int) in the type ImageView 
// is not applicable for the arguments (Drawable)
IV.setImageResource( getResources().getDrawable(j) );
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
int j = getResources().getIdentifier("hangman"+x, "drawable", getPackageName());
```

try this, if you are trying to get a drawable. and also as kcoppock said , just use j.

Comment: Yes, you need to specify the type of resource. Like in `R.drawable.hangman1` : the type is `drawable` not `imageView`.

Answer (score 4):

Because you're trying to pass in a Drawable. getDrawable(), as its name states, returns a Drawable object. setImageResource takes a resource ID, which is what getIdentifier will return. You should just pass `j` to `setImageResource()`.

Edit: Heh, and you also should use Yashwanth's answer, as he said. :)

(TEAMWORK!)

Comment: i already tried IV.setImageResource( j ); error disappears but image does not change.. :(

Answer (score 2):

combining both above solutions did the trick for me..here is code..
dnt know which answer i should accept..

```
ImageView IV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
int j = getResources().getIdentifier("hangman"+x, "drawable", getPackageName());
IV.setImageResource( j );
```

Comment: He also beat me by 16 seconds.

Comment: +1 for 16 seconds..lols...ok m gonna accept his answer..thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

from your xml file , use app:src instead of android:background, and from the activity file, use :

```
setImageDrawable(getRessource().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourRessource));
```